# Pass parameter with no argument, like '-Force'

Tags: powershell, function, parameters, arguments

I want to define a parameter to accept only the parameter name or alias when calling the function; i.e when calling a cmdlet and using '-Force'.

I have a 'User Input' function and would like to have an option for the function to accept optional input from the user (User can just hit 'Enter' and not provide input).

For an example when calling the function:

**$usrInput = uInput "Please Enter Computer Name" -AllowNull**

I'm trying to allow passing the '-AllowNull' and when passed, the function will accept an empty string. Instead of calling the function with an argument:

**$usrInput = uInput "Please Enter Computer Name" -AllowNull "Yes"**

or

**$usrInput = uInput "Please Enter Computer Name" -AllowNull $True**

I've tried different combinations of:

```
[AllowNull()]
[AllowEmptyString()]
[Validatenotnullorempty()]
[string]$allowNull
```

Some combinations will work, and I can check the value of $allowNull ('has value', bool. or $null/'Empty'), but I still need to pass an argument when calling the function; can't just use '-AllowNull'

I've even tried a '[switch]' parameter:

```
[switch]$allowNull
```

But that still requires a bool value as an argument when calling the function.

Comment: `[swtch]$allowNull` is correct. Does `& {param([switch]$AllowNull)} -AllowNull` not work?

Comment: Additionally, if you want to explicitly specify the state of a switch parameter you do it like this: ```-AllowNull:$true``` or ```-AllowNull:$false```, or even ```-AllowNull:$somevariable``` (i.e. the switch name, colon, boolean value or variablename, with no spaces). The naked ```-AllowNull``` syntax is equivalent to ```-AllowNull:$true```...

Comment: You are both correct. I guess I was making too many changes at once and just missed something. Simply setting the parameter to **[switch]$allowNull** without any attributes worked perfectly. Thanks for making me double check and simplify my code to realize it was correct in the first place. Thank you! +1

Comment: @mclayton: Actually while you typically see the space-less form (`-Foo:$false`), which is arguably preferable, spaces _are_ allowed; e.g.
`& { param([switch] $Foo) $Foo } -Foo: $false`
The only exception - yet to be fixed - is _CLI calls via `-File`_, where there currently mustn't be a space - see [GitHub issue #10838](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10838)